# "level of interest of " or "level of interest to "

Tags: grammar, word-choice, prepositions

Which of these options is more correct?

> 1. "level of interest of social dance"
> 2. "level of interest to social dance"?

To provide some context: the question as a part of a survey.

Comment: Neither one. _Interest_ marks its object with _**in**,_ not _of_ or _to_: _My interest in his writing is limited_.  Similarly with _interested_:  _She is not interested in dancing._

Answer (score 1):

Neither, it must be: level of interest in ...